# Tag for doing activities solo

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that most people would agree that doing outdoor activities solo carries unique risks and can be quite different (there is also probably a portion of users whose default reaction would be **don't**).

As far as tags go, as of right now there is one [solo-trekking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-trekking) but while the questions tagged with it all relate to being solo, not all relate to trekking, which is different from say kayaking or hiking.

There are also a few questions that have to do with being solo but are not tagged with [solo-trekking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-trekking).

**Update:**

After more thought, I don't like the idea of having a [solo](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo) used along with other tags since if for example I saw [solo](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo) and [hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking) used on a bunch of questions, I would think that we need to add [solo-hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-hiking)

Here is what I am thinking now, create tags for each type of activity like

- [solo-hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-hiking)
- [solo-backpacking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-backpacking)
- [solo-camping](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-camping)

and one [solo](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo) in case a question is asking about solo activities in general and not mentioning a specific activity like this [one](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/the-outdoors-solitude-and-dealing-with-loneliness).

These would be examples of questions that I am thinking of,

[Solo-backpacking in mountain lion country](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/solo-backpacking-in-mountain-lion-country)

[Dangers of solo hiking (in Ontario)](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14428/dangers-of-solo-hiking-in-ontario)

[If injured and lost, what are your biggest priorities for survival?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/if-injured-and-lost-what-are-your-biggest-priorities-for-survival)

[How does one steer a two-person kayak?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/how-does-one-steer-a-two-person-kayak)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is similar to discussions we had about other tags: It is about weighing up having a meta tag ("solo") vs strongly fractured tags. The reasoning is along the lines of a metatag not having a clear and consistent meaning, thus shouldn't be used at all (prime example in the broader network is "beginners" - beginners in what?).

For "solo" there is a rather big common denominator, as Charlie already mentioned: Consequences of mishaps are usually far bigger and far harder to cope with than in a team. That being sad, already your example question show that "solo" by itself does not restrict to such issues: The kayak question definitely is about doing something solo, but it is just about technique. However it pointless to have 10 different tags with 1 or 2 questions each. So I believe a compromise is in order, i.e. use both "solo" and specific tags if applicable. In case we get enough questions in the specific tag categories, using "solo" can easily be phased out on new questions (and it's existence on old questions doesn't harm anyone).

**TLDR:**
I believe "solo" qualifies as meta-tag and should whenever possible be avoided in favor of a more specific tag (e.g. "solo-trekking"). To account for the fact that most specific tags see hardly any use, I would not "ban" it and use it in parallel where appropriate.

Comment: Like how the tag [tag:gear] is being used?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Not sure what exactly you mean by that, but yes they are similar. Actually I am toying with deleting this answer. I believe I have been convinced of this myself, mostly based on the network wide anti-meta argument. Intuitively I am still thinking that having biggish tags combined with each other is better. It is just easier to use for search or filtering.